# VMware with TightVNC

Tags: vmware, vnc

Does anybody know any tutorial how to connect with VMware using TightVNC or can in few steps explain how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean connecting to a regular VM running a TightVNC server? That should just work.

Comment: Yes, I'm taking about that

Answer (score 0):

The only thing specific about doing this inside a VMware VM is to use a networking mode that can be reached from other computers. Using VMware, "bridged mode" networking is the most straightforward. With that your VM looks just like another device on the local network. Other than that, just treat the VM as a regular computer. Install the VNC server in the VM like you would a regular physical PC. Figure out that VM's IP address like you would any other computer, then use that address to connect from another machine.